# How to have Python accept multiple words as parameters?

Tags: python, python-3.x, bots, discord.py

This is the exact application I'm trying to get to work: I'm trying to allow the user to input multiple words for the 'status' parameter.

i.e. !setstatus playing League of Legends

displays "Playing League" instead of the whole string. I understand why, but how do I format the parameters to accept multiple words as a parameter? Can I even do that?

```
@bot.command() 
@commands.has_role('Bot Boss')
async def setstatus(ctx, action, status, url = None): 

    accepted_actions = ['playing', 'streaming', 'listening', 'watching']

    if action.lower() not in accepted_actions:
        await ctx.send("First parameter must be 'playing', 'streaming', 'listening', or 'watching'.")



    if action.lower() == 'playing':
        await bot.change_presence(activity = discord.Game(name = status))

    if action.lower() == 'streaming':
        await bot.change_presence(activity = discord.Streaming(name = status, url = url))

    if action.lower() == 'listening':
        await bot.change_presence(activity = discord.Activity(type=discord.ActivityType.listening, name=status))

    if action.lower() == 'watching':
        await bot.change_presence(activity=discord.Activity(type=discord.ActivityType.watching, name=status))
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This has nothing to do with Python, it only has to do with the discord bot library thing.

Accordingly, checking [the documentation for discord.py](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ext/commands/commands.html#parameters) provides three methods:

> To make use of a word with spaces in between, you should quote it:

or

> Sometimes you want users to pass in an undetermined number of parameters. The library supports this similar to how variable list parameters are done in Python:
>
> ```
> @bot.command()
> async def test(ctx, *args):
>     await ctx.send('{} arguments: {}'.format(len(args), ', '.join(args)))
> ```
>
> This allows our user to accept either one or many arguments as they please. This works similar to positional arguments, so multi-word parameters should be quoted.

or

> When you want to handle parsing of the argument yourself or do not feel like you want to wrap multi-word user input into quotes, you can ask the library to give you the rest as a single argument. We do this by using a keyword-only argument, seen below:
>
> ```
> @bot.command()
> async def test(ctx, *, arg):
>    await ctx.send(arg)
> ```

Comment: Ah. I thought I was stuck because when I put in multiple parameters, I used single quotes by habit and it didn't work. Your other 2 answers I will need to play around with to understand but thank you!

Answer (score -1):

I think you should look into ArgParse, a standard Python library that parses arguments.

```
import argparse
if __name__ == "__main__":     
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description='Process some integers.')
    parser.add_argument('command')
    parser.add_argument('multi_word')
    parser.add_argument('something_else')

    args = parser.parse_args()

    print(args.command)
    print(args.multi_word)
    print(args.something_else)
```

Output:

```
> python test.py playing "Counterstrike: Global Offensive" another
playing
Counterstrike: Global Offensive
another
```

Instead of printing, you call your function.

Edit: I'm sorry, I didn't see you're trying to use the Discord thing.

Comment: no worries, I still really appreciate the reply! :) someone didn't like your answer apparently